# Python Pandas dataframe doesn't update values based on my filter indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to update one column values if the index matches my specified condition:

```py
df['newCol'] = 0
df[df.month == 12]['newCol'] = 1
```

After I've done this, the value is not changed:

```py
df[df.month == 12]['newCol']
10120    0
Name: matched, dtype: int64
```

We cannot change pandas array values based on indexing like this?

Comment: Do not chain indexes. Do `df.loc[df.month==12, 'newCol'] = 1`

Comment: `df[df.month == 12]` is a copy so your are changing `newCol` of a copy

Comment: Why not use df.loc?

Comment: I was using df.loc[df.month == 12]['newCol'] which is not working. But using @QuangHoang's way, it's working well. Looks this copy and chain thing is such a matter in pandas.